# Flutter how to call initState() inside PageView for every pages (even if the page already loaded before)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a problem where `initState()` won't get called inside a PageView if the page was loaded before. And `dispose()` is also not getting called when changing pages. I have set `keepPage = false` but it still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `PageView` doesn't rebuild the page on changing the page. The solution to this is to use **`PageView.builder`**. For `initState()` and `dispose()` to call add them in the respective `PageView widgets`

Comment: Thanks, it kinda works i guess. Idk what's the problem, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: sure let me know if there's any other error.